# How to code, which look for a certain phrase/text in the folder by POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell.

I have been looking for how to code look for a certain phrase/text in the folder

and show output each file name.

I code this looks for a certain phrase which in this case, "v_lfy" in A file

```
select-string -path "C:\Users\kiki\Desktop\copy\allocation - Copy.prc"
-pattern "v_lfy"
```

but I would like to look for "v_lfy" from many files in the folder.

and output shows the each file name like C:\Users\kiki\Desktop\copy\allocation - Copy.prc

How should I code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files in the folder, then pipe them to `Select-String`

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\kiki\Desktop\copy' -Filter *.prc |Select-String -Pattern "v_lfy"
```

Comment: and -Recurse if you need to run through child folders.

Comment: What if there is other files like "money.sql" or "money.gnt" in the folder, so I would like to add code *.sql, *gnt, how can I code like that?